# Only displaying "tallest" bars in bar chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a clustered bar chart in PowerBI Desktop, where only the N "tallest" bars are displayed.

My dataset consists of a small number of rows but a large number of columns.

I have tried the following:

- Transform the table in absolute values (since I am interested in bar height, not negative/postive strictly)
- Try to apply the "top N" filter on the axis datafield

However, nothing happens. The chart currently looks like this (without applying the transformation of the absolute value): [Clustered bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Ke0.png)

I basically want the same chart, but only display the N tallest bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to pivot your table, so you have a "column name" field and a "value" field.

Then you need to use the TOP N on the Legend field, like this:
[image]

Filters:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! After some transposing and pivoting, I worked it out.
However, it does not seem to allow for different bars for different values on the X-axis (i.e if one value is not among the top 3 on Mar 21 but is so at a later occasion), but I might just handle it by making separate figures.

Comment: I believe that is a bit more complicated, you'll need a separate measure to rank the results per category and then apply a filter based on that rank.